# Retrieving a one to many Map on an entity using HQL

Tags: hql

I have a class called Product which has the following Map on it:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<SampleType, Sample<?>> samples = new BasicMap<SampleType, Sample<?>>();
```

I want to write an HQL query to get the map itself along with some other fields on the Product.

I tried the following:

SELECT product.id, product.name, index(sample), sample
FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.samples sample

But the above returns duplicate rows for Product and each entry in the map.

For example, if it looks like:

Product1 - {{SampleType1, Sample1}{SampleType2, Sample2}}

It returns 2 rows:

001, Product1, SampleType1, Sample1

001, Product1, SampleType2, Sample2

Instead, it should return something like:

001, Product1,{{SampleType1, Sample1}{SampleType2, Sample2}}

Thanks!